# HTTP 415 when calling Jersey multipart/mixed POST endpoint - fails with MultiPart as parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am implementing a REST endpoint in Jersey that should consume multipart/mixed requests in the format below:

```
content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--Boundary20171230945619789
manifest: ["Type1","Type2","Type3"]
content-length: 325

----Boundary20171230945619789
Content-Type: application/json

["string1","string2","string3"]
----Boundary20171230945619789
Content-Type: application/json

["string4","string5","string6"]
----Boundary20171230945619789
Content-Type: application/json

["string7","string8","string9"]
----Boundary20171230945619789--
```

The "manifest" header field contains a JSON array of string keys to schemas used for processing of each body part.

When I try to implement the request as follows:

```
@Path("request/test/post")
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
public Response tryPost(MultiPart multi) { ... }
```

I receive an HTTP 415 error:

> 2017-09-19 17:34:32.006 [http-nio-9909-exec-1] ERROR
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest:460 - A message body
>   reader for Java class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart,
>   and Java type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart,
>   and MIME media type multipart/mixed;
>   boundary=--Boundary20171230945619789 was not found. The registered
>   message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are: */* ->
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader

Jersey/Jackson won't properly parse the request into a MultiPart object. If I change the signature to:

```
@Path("request/test/post")
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
public Response tryPost(@HeaderParam("Manifest") String manifest, String rqBody){
    //etc here...
}
```

it works fine - `manifest` is populated with the JSON from the header field (which can be easily deserialized into an a List or Array of String), and `rqBody` is correctly populated with the request body. However, to use the request body this way I will have to do some ugly (and pitfall-laden) parsing and tokenizing.

I have registered the `MultiPartFeature` class with `ResourceConfig`, and tried most of the other options that looked helpful. Almost all the examples I can see with Jersey are using multipart/form-data; even the Jersey documentation itself has basically no examples of endpoints consuming multipart/mixed requests beyond an extremely cursory section.

Does anyone know what the issue here is? How do I properly implement the endpoint method to be able to read the request into a MultiPart object?

Thanks in advance for any/all help.